# where is this print BST function going wrong?

Tags: c, function, printing, binary-search-tree

so I have a print function which prints a binary search tree structure. It seems to work fine when i don't call the `leftRotate` function. but i want to print the tree after I call the `leftRotate` function, and it seems to not work - printing the wrong tree structure, missing some nodes. Anyone know where I am going wrong. Thanks.

Below is my full program:

```
// C program to insert a node in AVL tree
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define COUNT 10

// An AVL tree node
struct Node
{
    int key;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
    int height;
};

// A utility function to get maximum of two integers
int max(int a, int b);

// A utility function to get the height of the tree
int height(struct Node *N)
{
    if (N == NULL)
        return 0;
    return 1+max(height(N->left), height(N->right));
}

// A utility function to get maximum of two integers
int max(int a, int b)
{
    return (a > b)? a : b;
}

/* Helper function that allocates a new node with the given key and
    NULL left and right pointers. */
struct Node* newNode(int key)
{
    struct Node* node = (struct Node*)
                        malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    node->key = key;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    node->height = 0; // new node is initially added at leaf
    return(node);
}

// A utility function to right rotate subtree rooted with y
// See the diagram given above.
struct Node *rightRotate(struct Node *y)
{
    struct Node *x = y->left;
    struct Node *T2 = x->right;

    // Perform rotation
    x->right = y;
    y->left = T2;

    // Update heights
    y->height = height(y);
    x->height = height(x);

    // Return new root
    return x;
}

// A utility function to left rotate subtree rooted with x
// See the diagram given above.
struct Node *leftRotate(struct Node *x)
{
    struct Node *y = x->right;
    struct Node *T2 = y->left;

    // Perform rotation
    y->left = x;
    x->right = T2;

    // Update heights
    x->height = height(x);
    y->height = height(y);

    // Return new root
    return y;
}

// Get Balance factor of node N
int getBalance(struct Node *N)
{
    if (N == NULL)
        return 0;
    return height(N->left) - height(N->right);
}

// Recursive function to insert a key in the subtree rooted
// with node and returns the new root of the subtree.
struct Node* insert(struct Node* node, int key)
{
    /* 1. Perform the normal BST insertion */
    if (node == NULL)
        return(newNode(key));

    if (key < node->key)
        node->left = insert(node->left, key);
    else if (key > node->key)
        node->right = insert(node->right, key);
    else // Equal keys are not allowed in BST
        return node;

    /* 2. Update height of this ancestor node */
    node->height = height(node);

    /* 3. Get the balance factor of this ancestor
        node to check whether this node became
        unbalanced */
    int balance = getBalance(node);

    // If this node becomes unbalanced, then
    // there are 4 cases

    // Left Left Case
    if (balance > 1 && key < node->left->key)
        return rightRotate(node);

    // Right Right Case
    if (balance < -1 && key > node->right->key)
        return leftRotate(node);

    // Left Right Case
    if (balance > 1 && key > node->left->key)
    {
        node->left = leftRotate(node->left);
        return rightRotate(node);
    }

    // Right Left Case
    if (balance < -1 && key < node->right->key)
    {
        node->right = rightRotate(node->right);
        return leftRotate(node);
    }

    /* return the (unchanged) node pointer */
    return node;
}

// A utility function to print preorder traversal
// of the tree.
// The function also prints height of every node
void preOrder(struct Node *root)
{
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", root->key);
        preOrder(root->left);
        preOrder(root->right);
    }
}


void print2DUtil(struct Node*root, int space)
{
    // Base case
    if (root == NULL)
        return;
 
    // Increase distance between levels
    space += COUNT;
 
    // Process right child first
    print2DUtil(root->right, space);
 
    // Print current node after space
    // count
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = COUNT; i < space; i++)
        printf(" ");
    printf("%d\n", root->key);
 
    // Process left child
    print2DUtil(root->left, space);
}

// Wrapper over print2DUtil()
void print2D(struct Node*root)
{
   // Pass initial space count as 0
   print2DUtil(root, 0);
}
 

/* Driver program to test above function*/
int main()
{
struct Node *root = NULL;
    root = insert(root, 20);
    root = insert(root, 11);
    root = insert(root, 32);
    root = insert(root, 4);
    root = insert(root, 16);
    root = insert(root, 25);
    root = insert(root, 36);
    root = insert(root, 3);
    root = insert(root, 7);
    root = insert(root, 13);
    root = insert(root, 18);
    root = insert(root, 21);
    root = insert(root, 28);
    root = insert(root, 33);
    root = insert(root, 39);
    

/* The constructed AVL Tree would be
            30
        / \
        20 40
        / \  \
    10 25 50
*/
root = leftRotate(root);
print2D(root);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why does `leftRotate` return a value if you aren't going to use it? Perhaps `root = leftRotate(root);`?

Comment: @RetiredNinja have updated it, error is still there

Comment: @RetiredNinja i dont understand why the ```leftRotate``` function does a right rotate of the tree when its supposed to rotate left?

Comment: If you print the tree before the `leftRotate` call is it correct? The comment doesn't match the data you've provided so I'm not sure what you expect. If I make that change the same 15 modes are printed. Perhaps for debugging ease you should add fewer nodes.

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes if i print the tree before the ```leftRotate``` call it is correct (like i have mentioned in my post)

Comment: @RetiredNinja the problem is the fucntion ```leftRoate``` is rotating the tree right, when it is suppoed to do a left rotate.

Comment: Cannot reproduce... Nice balanced tree initially, then left-rotated (complete), then right-rotating restores the balance, all nodes present...

Comment: Cannot reproduce either (see it on [repl.it](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/BisqueIdenticalApplicationserver#main.c) ). The comment block in `main` does not depict the tree that the code has built, but that's all. Voting to close as not reproducible.